# comparing array to hashmap and deleting elements from hash in perl

Tags: perl, hashmap, compare

I have a file being read in then changed into an array then counted and put into a hash table.  I then read in another file that has stop words into an array. I want to take the array of stop words and compare it to the hash table and if a word from the stop words is a match then it deletes it from the hash table.

I'm curious as to what methods I could do to achieve this using perl. I wont post my code, because I'm refraining from having other people write my code. I just would like to know how I could go about this. If someone has a good website I could reference that could help.

Comment: It's difficult if you don't post code, but you can at least explain what you tried. Personally, I would remove the stop words from the array, then make the hash.

Comment: @gpojd why would you prefer to do that? I can do that though. Just move the array to hash around.  Is comparing an array to an array and deleting elements easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
my %table = some_sub_to_populate_table();
my @stop_words = some_sub_to_get_stopwords();
for my $stop_word ( @stop_words ) {
    delete $table{ $stop_word };
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, I asked someone else they said it would be easier to compare arrays to arrays, but I think it seems more logical to compare an array to a hash table and delete hashes instead of restricting an array every time.

Answer (score 1):

this should work, too

```
open FH,"<".$PATH or die $!;
my $table={};
while(<FH>){
    $table->{$_}=VALUE
}
close FH;
open FH,"<".$PATH2 or die $!;
my @arr=<FH>;
close $FH;
delete $table{$_} foreach(@arr);
```

regards

Comment: You should use the three-argument-version of `open` together with lexical filehandles. So for example `open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;`

Comment: You are constructing a hashref and then try to delete key within a hash, you should be more exact in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I would initially use the **simple loop solution** but am also interested on *other ways* to do it. Maybe you could try this one?

```
my %new_table = map { $_ => $old_table{$_} } grep { not $_ ~~ @stop_words } keys %old_table;
```

**1:** It gets all the hash keys not in @stop_words using **grep**:

```
grep { not $_ ~~ @stop_words } keys %old_table;
```

**2:** Using those keys, it creates a new hash using **map**:

```
my %new_table = map { $_ => $old_table{$_} }
```

If you will be transforming them into arrays, you could use array_minus of [Array::Utils](http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm)